# Sorting N unique elements into unique pairs, and then sorting those into X unique groups of Y pairs

Tags: algorithm, sorting

We have *n* unique elements. Let's say *n* = 8, and *N = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H}*.

We want to get all the unique combinations of these elements, in this case, that should yield 28 unique pairs.

```
[A, B]
[A, C]
[A, D]
[A, E]
[A, F]
[A, H]
[A, G]
[B, C]
[B, D]
[B, E]
[B, F]
[B, H]
[B, G]
[C, D]
[C, E]
[C, F]
[C, H]
[C, G]
[D, E]
[D, F]
[D, H]
[D, G]
[E, F]
[E, H]
[E, G]
[F, H]
[F, G]
[H, G]
```

We then want to take those pairs, and group them into *x* groups of *y* pairs. Let *X = 7* and *Y = 4*. No group should have an element represented more than once, and no pair should be used more than once across all *x* groups.

A simple brute force algorithm falls down here--it creates 4 groups of 4, 3 groups of 3, with 3 pairs unable to be grouped. This happens consistently.

```
***** Group 1 *****
Pair(element1=F, element2=G)
Pair(element1=E, element2=H)
Pair(element1=C, element2=D)
Pair(element1=A, element2=B)
***** Group 2 *****
Pair(element1=F, element2=H)
Pair(element1=E, element2=G)
Pair(element1=B, element2=C)
Pair(element1=A, element2=D)
***** Group 3 *****
Pair(element1=E, element2=F)
Pair(element1=D, element2=G)
Pair(element1=C, element2=H)
***** Group 4 *****
Pair(element1=D, element2=E)
Pair(element1=C, element2=F)
Pair(element1=B, element2=G)
Pair(element1=A, element2=H)
***** Group 5 *****
Pair(element1=D, element2=F)
Pair(element1=C, element2=E)
Pair(element1=B, element2=H)
Pair(element1=A, element2=G)
***** Group 6 *****
Pair(element1=D, element2=H)
Pair(element1=C, element2=G)
Pair(element1=B, element2=E)
Pair(element1=A, element2=F)
***** Group 7 *****
Pair(element1=B, element2=D)
Pair(element1=A, element2=C)
Pair(element1=H, element2=G)
```

We could double-down on the brute force approach and just discard a bad final grouping, randomize the order of the unique pairs and try again, but there has to be a cleaner (smarter) way to do this.

Doing a little digging, I think this might be a case of the [Exact Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover). Is that an accurate generalization here? If so, I can redirect my effort towards an Algorithm X implementation.  I'm skeptical, because I'm not just looking for an exact cover, I'm looking for an exact cover where each subset is the same size.

I realize this problem reads suspiciously like a homework problem, but I'm long out of school. Believe it or not this is just a couple devs trying to generate a Pair Programming schedule--failing miserably--and realizing we stumbled into a slightly interesting problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Errr, from your example, there are 28 unique pairs, and creating 7 groups of 4 pairs where a group does not represent an element more than once seems (from my gut feeling) not possible?

Comment: The difficulty with exact cover is that your starting data is arbitrary. Here, you're generating it yourself, and the way you do it guarantees that it has exactly `X=(n-1)` covers of `Y=n/2` pairs each. There's no reason a simple greedy approach won't work

Comment: It sounds more like a generalization of the [Social Golfer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SocialGolferProblem.html) problem.

Comment: Can you use the standard round-robin tournament scheduling algorithm? See https://nrich.maths.org/1443, scroll down for round-robin.